# Enable treat warnings as errors per file

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to enable treating warnings as errors per file?

I'm working on a large project and it's impossible to set it at project level, it would require a lot of work to fix thousands of errors due to treating all warnings as errors. And this kind of refactoring won't be approved anyway.

So I'd like to enable it per .cs file if possible.

Something like how C# 8 has with `#nullable enable` ?

Or maybe by some Roslyn magic? (if not a VS extension, at least a tool which parses the project files)

Comment: Since when [marking single radiobutton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoLt2.png) is *"impossible to set it at project level, it would require a lot of work"*

Comment: @Sinatr probably when it results in 4,000 warnings becoming 4,000 errors to fix =]

Comment: You can be selective about **which** warnings are not errors with the `<WarningsNotAsErrors>` project tag

Comment: @Sinatr: I think what OP meant to say was "impractical" rather than "impossible" - the requirement is to set warnings as errors for a single file (or at least a small number) rather than all files in the project.